# RTF Java Parser

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, document, rtf

here is my issue.

I need to read an RTF document and render to a webpage (some sort of google docs) but these documents are templates, the idea, is that user can only edit certain text and not the text that is marked to be "template logic".

So far I've seen a bunch of RTF libraries that performs only rendering but wont let you access an object that can be iterated dynamically to go over the structure of the RTF document.

My idea is to determine what can be editable and what can not, put all that info (images, text, tables, headers, footers) into a json and send it to my JS client.

Maybe this is a crazy idea, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When I read "template", I think "Velocity".  I wonder if you can solve this by separating template from dynamic data.  I wonder if you can solve this by letting users modify dynamic data and only marry it with the static, unedited template at the last minute.

Comment: No I can't the source of my data is an RTF document, that goes into HotDocs, so the idea is to come up with a approach of "google docs" to display the template to users, but that whatever they do, they can't modify script logic, otherwise we would have to change tons of apps that already use this, thanks for your input :)

I think i might be able to convert from RTF to XML with itext, I'm exploring that option ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) can help because it lets you use documents and templates and you can extract from Docmosis an "analysis" of the template (eg a list of fields).  It's hard to be sure if it will fit your purpose though from your description.  Please note I work for the company that produces Docmosis.